# GLIB usage without mainloop

Tags: c, glib, dbus, gdbus

I have a problem using Glib. I want to subscribe to a dbus signal without launching the mainloop with **g_main_loop_run**.

I create the connection to the correct bus and call the function **g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe**.

I replaced the call to **g_main_loop_run** in the main function by a while(1).

Unfortunately, it's not working. If I understand correctly the GLib, there is no need to launch the mainloop for a such treatment.

Please help.

Sample code :

```
session_bus = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION,
                             NULL,
                             NULL );


g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(session_bus,
                                   "org.freedesktop.Notifications",
                                   "org.freedesktop.Notifications",
                                   "NotificationClosed",
                                   "/org/freedesktop/Notifications",
                                   NULL,
                                   G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                                   (GDBusSignalCallback) onNotifClosed,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL );

loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
g_main_loop_run(loop);
g_main_loop_unref(loop);
g_object_unref(session_bus);
```

Comment: "there is no need to launch the mainloop" - on the contrary, the only way it will work is to run a main loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand correctly the GLib, there is no need to launch the
>   mainloop for a such treatment.

If you want to wait for incoming DBus events, you have to run main loop. What main loop does is to wait and process events, and you want to wait and then process events. As an alternative to `g_main_loop_run`, you may try to run `g_main_context_iteration` in `while(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar need to process GLib events in a non-blocking manner and I couldn't find a complete answer anywhere, so I'm posting my solution here for reference.

As [el.pescado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226648/el-pescado) said, the one alternative to [`g_main_loop_run()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-loop-run) is calling [`g_main_context_iteration()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-iteration) repeatedly on the context of the [`GMainLoop`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GMainLoop) object. This may be done in a loop for example, allowing some `intervening_task()` to be performed between event processing cycles until some sort of `termination_condition()` is met:

```
GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new();
while (!termination_condition())
{
  g_main_context_iteration(g_main_loop_get_context(loop), FALSE);
  intervening_task();
}

g_main_loop_unref(loop);
```

In the snippet above, the loop context is retrieved by [`g_main_loop_get_context()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-loop-get-context), and any pending GLib events are processed by [`g_main_context_iteration()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-iteration). Setting the `may_block` argument to `FALSE` causes the function to return immediately if there are no pending events (otherwise it would block waiting for something to process).

It's worth noticing however that if the above is all you want to do, then you might as well stick to `g_main_loop_run()` and use [`g_timeout_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) or [`g_idle_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) to register the intervening task and termination condition as event callbacks — the later would call [`g_main_loop_quit()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-loop-quit) to terminate the loop. The point here is not to use that code as-is, but merely to demonstrate how GLib events can be processed in a non-blocking manner, so it can be integrated to the main loop of another framework. e.g. Qt or ROS.

Comment: You’ve basically reinvented a poor version of `g_main_loop_run()` there. If you look at the [source code for `g_main_loop_run()`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/master/glib/gmain.c#L4271), it does the equivalent of calling `g_main_context_iteration()` in a loop.

You would be better off creating a `GSource` for your `intervening_task()` (for example, using `g_idle_source_new()`) and adding that to the main context. Then your intervening task can be polled/waited for in the same `poll()` call as the rest of the event sources in the main context.

Comment: Yes, but you miss the point. The purpose of that code snippet is not to be used as-is, but to demonstrate how GLib events can be processed in a non-blocking manner. Then you're free to apply that however you need.

Comment: In my case for example, I wanted to call `g_main_context_iteration()` from a [ROS timer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) callback function. If I had seen a snippet like that, it would have made things easier for me, even though my finished code looks nothing like that.

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that you were calling `g_main_context_iteration()` with `may_block` set to false. i.e. Chaining the GLib main loop to another main loop, rather than the other way round. What you’ve said makes sense in that case, sorry for the misinterpretation.

One simplification you could make is to drop the `GMainLoop` entirely, and construct/use `GMainContext` directly (`g_main_context_new()` or `g_main_context_default()`). `GMainLoop` is just a closure which contains a `GMainContext` and an exit condition.